How to repair paint damage from bird droppings
I took my car on holiday to France last summer. Our parking spot was near a tree and the car's paintwork was subjected to daily assault from birds (or more precisely, their droppings).
Some of the droppings were washed off in the rain, but other more stubborn bits remained stuck until we got home, and took a lot of gentle hand washing to soften and remove. I should have washed the car on holiday, but you live and learn I suppose.
When I washed the car I discovered a small section of paint on the roof beginning to flake away beneath one of the more stubborn pieces. It measures around 8mm across. Please see attached photo.
Is there anything I can do to step this getting worse, for example, by placing a small amount of lacquer over it? Could a paint specialist fix this issue (or at least improve it/stop further damage) without resorting to an expensive respray?
The car is a silver Kia, 2.5 years old.
Thanks

I've had to fix similar paint situations many times before with varying results. If that area is measured in millimeters (vs. multiple centimeters), I would suggest getting a touch-up paint kit that matches the color of your car (the dealer will certainly sell you one). Since there's nothing going through the paint to the metal (increasing rust risk), there's little chance you can make things too terribly worse.
The procedure that I've followed is approximately:

I've generally left any remaining paint flecks within that sort of area in place vs. trying to pry them loose.
Using the brush applicator, add little wee drops of paint within that void. No need to lather it on, just looking for a thin first coat.
Let it dry.
Repeat steps 2 and 3 as many times as you think appropriate.
If the new paint looks fine at this point, you can decide not to do any sort of sanding. The kit may include instructions on how to blend the edges but I'm always wary of that sort of thing due to the risk that I'll make a bigger problem for myself.
There's usually a container of clear coat in these kits as well. Apply that as with steps 3 and 4. Many layers is good as you already have a weak spot in the paint.

Usually, I've ended up with a paint repair that lasts for years and looks much better than when I started. The paint doesn't look brand new, of course, but I'm generally glad that I went to the effort.

Thank you for the detailed answer - I will give this a go. Good suggestion asking the manufacturer for touch-up paint, rather than the lottery that is Halfords.
